# FormatNumber replacing number with 0

Tags: vb.net, formatting, decimal

Not understanding this:
Number returned from DataReader: 185549633.66000035

We have a requirement to maintain the number of decimal places per a User Choice.

For example: maintain 7 places.

We are using:

```
FormatNumber(dr.Item("Field"), 7, TriState.false, , TriState.True)
```

The result is: 185,549,633.6600000.
We would like to maintain the 3 (or 35) at the end.

When subtracting two numbers from the resulting query we are getting a delta but trying to show these two numbers out to 6,7,8 digits is not working thus indicating a false delta to the user.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Is the actual data of type `Double` or `Decimal`?

Comment: The table the query pulls from for the fields is datatype decimal.

Comment: That's not what I asked.  What matters is the .NET data type that that maps to.  Your code is dealing with .NET data so it's .NET data types that matter.  I've tested and the behaviour you describe occurs for `Double` but not for `Decimal`, so it must be `Double`.

Answer (score 2):

Based on my testing, you must be working with `Double` values rather than `Decimal`.  Not surprisingly, the solution to your problem can be found in the documentation.

For a start, you should not be using `FormatNumber`.  We're not in VB6 anymore ToTo.  To format a number in VB.NET, call `ToString` on that number.  I tested this:

```
Dim dbl = 185549633.66000035R
Dim dec = 185549633.66000035D

Dim dblString = dbl.ToString("n7")
Dim decString = dec.ToString("n7")

Console.WriteLine(dblString)
Console.WriteLine(decString)
```

and I saw the behaviour you describe, i.e. the output was:

```
185,549,633.6600000
185,549,633.6600004
```

I read the documentation for the `Double.ToString` method (note that `FormatNumber` would be calling `ToString` internally) and this is what it says:

> By default, the return value only contains 15 digits of precision although a maximum of 17 digits is maintained internally. If the value of this instance has greater than 15 digits, ToString returns PositiveInfinitySymbol or NegativeInfinitySymbol instead of the expected number. If you require more precision, specify format with the "G17" format specification, which always returns 17 digits of precision, or "R", which returns 15 digits if the number can be represented with that precision or 17 digits if the number can only be represented with maximum precision.

I then tested this:

```
Dim dbl = 185549633.66000035R

Dim dblString16 = dbl.ToString("G16")
Dim dblString17 = dbl.ToString("G17")

Console.WriteLine(dblString16)
Console.WriteLine(dblString17)
```

and the result was:

```
185549633.6600004
185549633.66000035
```

Comment: For the record, I've looked at the internal implementation of `FormatNumber` and it would indeed have called `ToString("n7")` on the data using your original code.

Comment: Thank you for this information. This was great! We have two situations where this issue is occurring. One is writing the results (185549633.66000035) from a field in the query to a DataTable whose field is Decimal DataType. Using the immediate window we see the 185549633.66000035. Once the DataTable is filled we use the immediate window again and the value returned is 185549633.66.

Comment: We are not creating Decimal Variables like in your examples. The values from the DataReader appear to be providing the "FULL" value, yet after adding to the DataTable they are cut off. I will create a new comment for the other situation which was the reason for the original stackoverflow post.

Comment: The other situation, again not using Decimal Variable, is writing the results of the DataReader (and we've checked immediate window and the results are the "FULL" number - and writing this directly to a Grid. In order to format the value we have a Function we call (get_Value(ByVal iValue as Decimal, ByVal numdigits as integer). The value passed to iValue is the "Full" number. However, when checking the iValue parameter, before we get to the formatting, it's already been cutoff to two digits pass the decimal.

Comment: So, in summary, to your point, we don't see anywhere where we are using "Double". The original value comes from the DataReader. We are taking these values and trying to format then with a specific number of decimal places first and then writing them to a cell in a grid. We can get the number of decimal places but we lose the numbers out past the second decimal place.

Comment: Just for further clarification: here is how we are creating our datatable fields:  DTCost.Columns.Add("DollarField", Type.GetType("System.Decimal")). All of the fields in the DataTable are of Decimal type.

Comment: I'll do some more testing myself because it really appears to me that the behaviour you mention occurs with `Double` but not `Decimal`.  Can you specify what database you're using and the exact data type, as well as provide the query you're using?

Comment: I would agree with you that it would appear Double is being used. But the DataTable is Decimal Type, the fields in the table from the Database are Decimal as well. The Database is SQLite. I will provide the query in the next comment.

Comment: SELECT Sum(CASE WHEN [DataType] = 'A' THEN [Hours] Else 0 END) [ActualHrs], Sum(CASE WHEN [DataType] = 'A' THEN ([Dollars]+[Overhead]+[G&A]+[COM]) Else 0 END) [ActualsDols], Sum(CASE WHEN [DataType] = 'E' AND [Period] > " & gateMonth & " THEN [Hours] Else 0 END) [ETCHours], Sum(CASE WHEN [DataType] = 'E' AND [Period] > " & gateMonth & " THEN ([Dollars]+[Overhead]+[G&A]+[COM]) Else 0 END) [ETCDols] FROM [FF_ROLLUP] WHERE [RollupType] = 'D';

Comment: This is interesting. Created a Variable of Decimal called "ActDollars". Assigned the Value of the field from the query..like here: Dim ActDollars As Decimal = dr.Item("ActualsDols")...below is the Immediate Window results.

Comment: ?dr.Item("ActualsDols")
185549633.66000041
?ActDollars
185549633.66

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with the boxing and unboxing that occurs due to the `DataRow` storing the value as an `Object`.  I haven't had a chance to investigate further yet.

Comment: Believe the issue is SQLite. Results of SUM is not decimal. If we extract the fields we want to sum individual, and then sum prior to inserting into Datatable we get the decimal digits.