# SQLite SUM Returns Integer?

Tags: sqlite, sum, format

According to the documentation:

"Introduction to SQLite SUM function. The SUM function is an aggregate function that returns the sum the non-NULL values or only the distinct values in a group. SUM([ALL. ... If any input value is neither an integer nor a NULL value, the result of the SUM function is a floating point value."

We are performing SUMs and for example one field is returning from the datareader: 687224.53200000292

However when we try and format: dr.Item("Field").ToString("n7") we get error:

-Immediate Window
InnerException: {"Input string was not in a correct format."}
IsTransient: False
Message: "Conversion from string ""n7"" to type 'Integer' is not valid."

All of the Fields in the table we are summing are either data type FLOAT or DECIMAL.

Was hoping some SQLite experts could explain more and provide information on what we are doing wrong or not understanding correctly.

Comment: The question above really stems from this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52231214/formatnumber-replacing-number-with-0

Comment: Based on that other question, you're using Visual Basic? I suspect that whatever `dr.Item("Field")` returns is not what you think it is, and the `ToString()` method you're actually calling is thus not the one you want.

Comment: Yes. VB. Not sure what you mean by "dr.item("Field") returns is not what you think it is"...when in Immediate Window it's 687224.53200000292. This looks decimal. But to your point if we use the Format(dr.item("Field"),"#,#0.0000000") we do not get an error. However when we try and write this value to a DataTable into a field of type decimal the result is  687224.53. However if we modify the query and pull the two fields separately and then Sum them outside the query and insert into the Datatable the result is 687224.53200000292. So our question what is SQLite returning when Summing fields?

Comment: I mean exactly what I say. Your code acts like whatever `dr.Item("Field")` returns is a number (Double in vb-speak? Decimal? Something like that.). The error message suggests it's an object of some other type, with a `ToString()` method that does something different from the one you think you're using and takes different arguments. If VB has a way to find out the type of an object at runtime, I'd start with that to help narrow it down.